# Scheme - Can't bind name in null syntactic environment: tmp

Tags: scheme, syntax-error

Hello I am trying to figure out how to define my variable inside an if-statement in scheme. I keep getting the error ;Can't bind name in null syntactic environment: tmp....

From everything I have read online my syntax is correct. I don't understand how I keep getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
(if (list? seq2)
    (if (list? seq1)
        (begin
          (define tmp (car seq1))
          (if (list? tmp)
               #t
               #f))
        #f)
    #f)
```

The True False returns are for the sake of testing so I can see where things end up.

Comment: Where did you read that your example is valid?

Answer (score 2):

Really, there's nothing wrong with your code... I would describe its issues as being mostly historical.

In Racket, for instance, your code signals an error, but you can rewrite your `begin` as a `let () ...` and everything works fine:

```
(if (list? seq2)
    (if (list? seq1)
        (let ()
          (define tmp (car seq1))
          (if (list? tmp)
               #t
               #f))
        #f)
    #f)
```

Historically, `define` was allowed in Scheme only at the top level. Scheme relatives such as Racket have been broadening the set of contexts in which `define` is allowed, but `begin` is still not a context where `define` is allowed.

EDIT: s/but `begin`/but `begin` in an `if` branch/

Comment: `begin` forms can contain definitions if they are in a valid position for a definition, e.g. the beginning of a `let` body `(let () (begin (define...`

Comment: The [Racket Style Guide](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Conditionals%29) recommends using `cond` rather than `if` for that precise reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need use `define` there. You can use let instead. Here is an example:

```
(if (list? seq2)
    (if (list? seq1)
        (let ((tmp (car seq1)))
          (if (list? tmp)
              #t
              #f))
        #f)
    #f)
```

Comment: Both `define` and `let` "define variables".

Answer (score 0):

There are logic short circuiting syntax called `and` and `or`. Basically `(and expr1 expr2 expr3)` is the same as `(if expr1 (if expr2 expr3 #f) #f)`. I bet you notice a similarity with your code so here goes:

```
(and (list? seq2)
     (list? seq1) 
     (list? (car seq1)))
```

If any of those turn out to be `#f` it will stop there and it will be the result of the whole form. With `or` it stops at the first true value (anything but `#f`). Since it's short circuiting it wont try `(car seq1)` if `(list seq1)` is `#f`.

The variable `tmp` wasn't needed but if you ever need that use `let`:

```
(let ((tmp expression))
  (if (not (null? tmp))
      tmp
      #f))
```

This is of course done to not have to do `expression` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using MIT-Scheme and learned the `(define)` cannot be used inside the `(if )` form because of how `(if)` creates it's own temporary lexical scope that somehow interrupts `(define)`.

However, as a work around you can flip the `if` and `define` procedures:

`(define x (if ..))`